# How do I interpolate a value (output) with 3 or more input variables in Dymola?

Tags: interpolation, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

[image: example]

[image]

The picture shows the problem that I want to solve.
I will have the data (output from inputs) as a table in csv format.

Interpolating with 2 inputs and one output is no problem. I could solve this with the combiTable2Dv. Can I extend this table to solve my problem? Under parameters I saw a setting option for the dimensions.[image]

Update:
I have now created a map with 4 inputs and 1 output in the SDF format. (see picture 4)
I have loaded this into the SDF.NDTable and get the following error message.
[image]

[image]

```
This is my Error in Dymola:

Check of Unnamed2:

Multiple sources for causal signal in the same connection set.
inside output m_in.y =inside output n.y =inside input nDTable.u[4] =inside output p_in.y =inside output p_out.y

The problem is structurally singular.

It has 13 scalar unknowns and 13 scalar equations.
The Real part has 12 unknowns and 12 equations.
The Integer part has 1 unknowns and 1 equations.
The Boolean part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.
The String part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.

The model could not be deduced to be symbolically well-posed.
The model has
9+nDTable.nin
scalar unknowns and
13
scalar equations.
However, exploiting the given numerical settings of parameters gives the same number of unknowns and equations:
13

Attempting to further localize singularity.

Singularity of Unnamed2 is at the top level.

The model Unnamed2 is structurally singular.

Multiple sources for causal signal in the same connection set.
inside output m_in.y =inside output n.y =inside input nDTable.u[4] =inside output p_in.y =inside output p_out.y

Some elements of the input connector u of nDTable are not connected from the outside.
It is likely that they all should have been connected, and recursive check assumes this.
The missing connection is a likely cause of errors in the model.

WARNINGS have been issued.

ERRORS have been issued.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Regarding your question with "dimensions":

The model `Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2Dv` does have a parameter `n`. Assuming this is what you are referring to: This basically creates a vector of tables which do a look-up/interpolation based on the same source data (=table/file) for a vector of (two) inputs resulting in a vector of outputs. Inputs and outputs are therefore vectors of size `n`. So this will likely not help in the given case.

##### The original issue:

From what I understand, you need a table with there inputs, or three independent variables. Tables of this kind are not provided with the Modelica Standard Library. In Dymola I know about two options, which you will find under File -> Libraries:

- `DataFiles.TableND` which is based on .mat (version 4) files and a bit aged by now.
- `SDF.NDTable` uses .sdf files, which are based on HDF5, https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF. Dymola comes with a tool called "SDF Editor" which will enable you to view and edit those files in a GUI.
  NOTE: The GUI is limited to three dimensions as this is enough in most cases. You can use [Python](https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-Python) or [MATLAB](https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-MATLAB) functions to create datasets with more independent variables. A subset of functions is also available in the Modelica Library `SDF.Functions` which can be used from `.mos` scripts.

Both of the above packages provide functions which allow the creation of the necessary files from Dymola and/or Matlab. Those should be documented well enough to be usable.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I have now worked a bit with the SDF Editor and the SDF.NDTable. 

Can I set up a 4D or 5D matrix with the SDF.NDTable?
I have seen in the settings options that I can only set 3 dimensions.

Comment: SDF should be able to create up to 32 dimensions. Not sure which option should limit it to three dimensions...

Comment: I have added a photo to the 3 dimensions. Here I can not set more than 3. 
Maybe you have an example for a 4D Matrix for the SD.NDtable.

Comment: Yes, the GUI is limited to three as after this it gets rather difficult to use. I have edited the original answer - hoping this helps. I didn't create SDF files for a while, so I don't have an example ready...

Comment: Hello, @Markus A. I have now created a dummy matrix in the SDF file using Python. Can Dymola interpolate this matrix into SDF.NDTable in the form as shown in the picture? The simulation is not working.

Comment: A bit difficult to debug without the actual model. From the message and the screenshots I see two potential problems:
(1) The connections to the table which could have a wrong index and (2) that there are no scales attached to the table.
As it is dummy values only, could you upload the model and sdf file?

Comment: Ok. I am uploading the files to Google Drive. I don't see any way to upload a file in the editing area. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lcjyQWbBcq0uQ8E0m3gNlEwIsgtctRKW?usp=sharing

Comment: There are two problems with the files: (1) Modelica part: The connections to the input of the table are all pointing to the fourth input. This is represented by the `connect()` statements containing `nDTable.u[4]`. The `4` means that this is connected to the fourth element of the input vector. As you have this multiple times, the error "Multiple sources for causal signal in the same connection set." is triggered. You need to change the index to range from one to four.

Comment: (2) The .sdf file only has two dimensions. You need to build one with four dimensions to have as many independent variables/dimensions/scales as the table has inputs. Every input of the table represents one independent axis. To build the 4D table you will need to use either MATLAB or Python as I think this is not possible from the Modelica Library...